# Simultaneous Linear Equations Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\left(5,k\right)$ is a solution of the equation $2x + y - 7 = 0$, find the value of $k$.

There is no $k$ in the equation. I am not understanding where $k$ came from. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put $x = 5$ and calculate the value for $y$. Here $k$ is the value for $y$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I found the answer!